# What is the recommended way to install pip on Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Tags: python, ubuntu-core, pip

I would like to provision Docker running on Ubuntu Core with Ansible. For that I need to get `docker-py` on the machine. Snappy already comes with Python installed, but `pip` is not provided.

Running the usual script from `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` results in an error:

> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.0.dist-info'

(which of course is makes sense given the architecture of the OS)

Is there a recommended way to get `pip` / `docker-py` (or other Python libraries) installed on Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want your own snap, which uses the Docker snap as a framework. In 16.04 you would use a different mechanism to connect to Docker, but in 15.04 the "framework" mechanism was the right way to get this done.

In your own snap you can of course do whatever you want :)

Comment: *Technically*, 16.04 answers are off-topic here before [21/4/2016](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule), but in *your* case, I'll let it slide as that's probably the only thing you can think of until then!  **:P ;-)**.  Drop by in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) some time to wow the foot soldiers some time...