# Can I install Python 2.7 and pip on snappy Ubuntu Core 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, python, snap, ubuntu-core, pip

This **does not** seems to answer the question: [What is the recommended way to install pip on Snappy Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742731/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-install-pip-on-snappy-ubuntu-core)

It appears that Ubuntu Core 16.04 only has Python 3.
How do I get Python 2 if there is no such a snap?
This system's rootfs is completely read-only and does not even have `dpkg`.

The `chroot` based "classic mode" does not work (or at least, not straightforward), because I am considering to use it in a system service style program that starts with the system.
Maybe you think I am using snappy Ubuntu Core in the wrong way, but that is what I have now and cannot switch to a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you installed the classic environment, this link can give you a clue:

https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project

As long as I remember, you can install it using sudo apt-get or even installing Miniconda (with Python 2) for ARM.

Be sure to run:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

... before running pip, otherwise you'll get locale error.

There is a lot of other issues when installing Python libraries. Updating `setuptools` solve some of them.